# Create assembly in SQL

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2014

I tried to create assembly:

> CREATE ASSEMBLY SendSmsWSI from 'C:\Development\TestStas\SendSmsWSIntegration\SendSmsWSIntegration\SendSmsWSIntegration\bin\Debug\SendSmsWSIntegration.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE

And received this error:

> Msg 10301, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Assembly 'SendSmsWSIntegration' references assembly 'system.servicemodel, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

Then I tried:

> CREATE ASSEMBLY
>   [System.ServiceModel]
>   from'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.ServiceModel.dll'with
>   permission_set = UNSAFE

But here, I have this kind of error:

> Msg 6544, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'System.ServiceModel' failed because assembly 'microsoft.visualbasic.activities.compiler' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly. 
>   Unverifiable PE Header/native stub.

What have I do in order to create the first assembly I mentioned?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you doing this on? [Update your question's tags](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34995737/edit) with this information.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: I edited your question and updated your tags, in the future you should try to do this your self. I also deleted my answer because it would only have been the correct answer if you had been running 2008 R2 or older.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use WCF in SQLCLR. I just tested on my local 2016 CTP3 and it still gives the same error. There's an issue for this, marked as "Won't Fix" here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/809697 - they just provide the link to the official list of supported assemblies:

- Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
- Mscorlib.dll
- System.Data.dll
- System.dll
- System.Xml.dll
- Microsoft.VisualC.dll
- CustomMarshalers.dll
- System.Security.dll
- System.Web.Services.dll
- System.Data.SqlXml.dll
- System.Transactions.dll
- System.Data.OracleClient.dll
- System.Configuration.dll